# Передача значений между классами

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, gui

Как передать значение `mean` в другой класс? 
Ниже есть класс `parametr`. Но туда, вроде, не передается

```
class ClassesPage1(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    ...
    def check(self):
        a = 0
        for checkBox in self.listCheckBox:
            if checkBox.isChecked():
                a += 1
        mean = a / 4

        if mean == 1:
            self.label_1.setText('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n    Среднее значение: 1')
        elif mean == 0:
            self.label_1.setText('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n    Среднее значение: 0')
        else:
            self.label_1.setText('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n    Среднее значение: ' + str(mean))

    def nextId(self):
        return Wizard.class4

class parametrs:
    par = ClassesPage1()
    print par.mean
```

Comment: Что значит "вроде"? В программировании используется двоичная система, тут не бывает вроде. Или передается, или нет.

Comment: @Эникейщик Суть вопроса от этого не меняется

Comment: Не меняется, когда есть понятный вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Эникейщик Вопрос конкретный - как передать значение из одного класса в другой. Об этом я и написал в заголовке

Comment: на этот ваш конкретный вопрос есть ответы в каждом учебнике по питону. Вы привели в вопросе код. Если с ним есть проблема (а проблема там есть, и не одна), то приложите усилия, чтобы другие поняли в чем у вас затруднения.

Comment: Если вам не понятен вопрос, можете просто закрыть тему. Более понятно эту проблему сформулировать невозможно.

Comment: А если вам лень читать сообщения об ошибках, то, может быть, не стоит тратить время на программирование? А вопрос мне понятен, не переживайте. Но не вижу смысла помогать человеку, который сам ничего не сделал, чтобы помочь себе.

Comment: Спасибо, но, наверное, я уже что-то пробовал писать в коде, и что-то не получалось, поэтому я и обращаюсь к форуму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо обратить внимание на ООП. Если вы хотите получить доступ к объектам в других методах класса и т.п., эти объекты должны быть экземплярами класса.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ClassesPage1(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                           # +++ parent=None 
        super(ClassesPage1, self).__init__()
        self.setTitle("...")
        self.setSubTitle("...")

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label_1')

        self.checkBox_1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('cb1 ...')
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('cb2 ...')
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('cb3 ...')
        self.checkBox_4 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('cb4 ...')

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.checkBox_4)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.checkBox_1.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.checkBox_2.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.checkBox_3.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.checkBox_4.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        
        self.listCheckBox = [self.checkBox_1, self.checkBox_2, self.checkBox_3, self.checkBox_4] 
        self.a = 0  
        
        self.parent = parent                                                   # +++  !!! 
        self.mean = 0                                                          # +++  !!! 
        
    
    def check(self):
        self.a = 0                                                             # +++ self.a
        for checkBox in self.listCheckBox:
            if checkBox.isChecked():
                self.a += 1                                                    # +++ self.a
        self.mean = self.a / 4                                                 # +++ self.mean
        ''' ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
        if self.mean == 1:
            self.label_1.setText('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n    Среднее значение: 1')
        elif self.mean == 0:
            self.label_1.setText('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n    Среднее значение: 0')
        else:
            self.label_1.setText('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n    Среднее значение: ' + str(self.mean))
        '''
        
        self.label_1.setText(f'Среднее значение: {self.mean}')                 # +++
        self.parent._print()                                                   # +++

    def nextId(self):
        return Wizard.class4


class Parametrs:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.par = ClassesPage1(self)
        self.par.show()
        print(f'__init__: par.mean = {self.par.mean}')
    
    def _print(self):
        print(f'par.mean = {self.par.mean:.2f}')
     
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Parametrs()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]